# Why does Nokogiri's to_xhtml create new `id` attributes from `name`?

Tags: ruby, xhtml, nokogiri, libxml2

Consider the following code:

```
require 'nokogiri' # v1.5.2
doc = Nokogiri.XML('<body><a name="foo">ick</a></body>')

puts doc.to_html
#=> <body><a name="foo">ick</a></body>

puts doc.to_xml
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <body>
#=>   <a name="foo">ick</a>
#=> </body>

 puts doc.to_xhtml
 #=> <body>
 #=>   <a name="foo" id="foo">ick</a>
 #=> </body>
```

Notice the new `id` attribute that has been created.

1. Who is responsible for this, Nokogiri or libxml2?
2. Why does this occur? (Is this enforcing a standard?)
   *The closest I can find is [this spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_8) describing how you **may** put both an `id` and `name` attribute with the same value.*
3. Is there any way to avoid this, given the desire to use the `to_xhtml` method on input that may have `<a name="foo">`?

*This problem arises because I have some input I am parsing with an `id` attribute on one element and a separate element with a `name` attribute that happens to conflict.*

Comment: Gosh I just wasted 2 hours of my life until I realized it was doing this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently [it's a feature](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/562) of libxml2. In http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10 we find:

> In XML, fragment identifiers are of type `ID`, and there can only be a single attribute of type `ID` per element. Therefore, in XHTML 1.0 the `id` attribute is defined to be of type `ID`. In order to ensure that XHTML 1.0 documents are well-structured XML documents, XHTML 1.0 documents **MUST use the `id` attribute when defining fragment identifiers** on the elements listed above.
> [...]
> Note that in XHTML 1.0, the `name` attribute of these elements is formally deprecated, and will be removed in a subsequent version of XHTML.

The best 'workaround' I've come up with is:

```
# Destroy all <a name="..."> elements, replacing with children
# if another element with a conflicting id already exists in the document
doc.xpath('//a[@name][not(@id)][not(@href)]').each do |a|
  a.replace(a.children) if doc.at_css("##{a['name']}")
end
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like this is the culprit: http://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/xmlsave.c?id=v2.7.8#n1291. The comment above that bit of code is “C.8”, which I’m guessing refers to [section C.8 of the XHTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_8) which talks about `id`s and `name`s.

Comment: @matt Thanks; that's the same section I linked to in my question. Perhaps my reading comprehension skills aren't up-to-snuff, but I'm not sure how C.8 directly implies this requirement (while 4.10, from my answer above, clearly does). But it's great that you found that source code line and comment.

Comment: Well _my_ reading comprehension skills certainly need work as I hadn't noticed the link in your question. I agree section C.8 doesn’t seem to require this whilst 4.10 does.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could add some other `id` value to these elements to prevent libxml adding its own.

```
doc.xpath('//a[@name and not(@id)]').each do |n|
  n['id'] = n['name'] + 'some_suffix'
end
```

(Obviously you’ll need to determine how to create a unique `id` value for your document).